# Dynamically added EditTexts focus goes from first to last when keyboard next button is clicked

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am adding edittext dynamically in a linear layout. when I start editing the first edit text and then press next button on the keyboard, the focus goes to the last one rather than going to the second one. Here is my Activity code..

```
LinearLayout layout =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       final View childView = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null);
       TextView questionText = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.questionId);
       EditText editText = (EditText) childView.findViewById(R.id.enterAnswerTextId);

       questionText.setText("Whats up");
       layout.addView(childView);
       childView.setTag(i);
    }
```

Activity is just a Linear Layout. And the tab item layout which I am inflating

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/separatorId"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/questionId"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/enterAnswerLayoutId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enterAnswerTextId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Enter Answer"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext|actionDone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by doing this

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define where to go for next focus

```
  editText.setNextFocusForwardId(R.id.secondView);
```

also you can set id in this way

```
view.setId(/*some unique integer as id*/)
```

Comment: I am adding edittext dynamically so there is no unique Ids for all edittext

Comment: you can use view.setId();